# How to render collection_check_box for this scenario

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, mongodb, mongoid

I am new to mongodb and trying to learn with Rails. I am using mongoid gem.
So my app has a User resource which should have a name, email, address and subscriptions.
Name, email and address fields can take any value user desire to type. But subscriptions are selected from a master list of available subscriptions. I have to render collection_check_boxes for available Subscriptions, and user selects what he wants and submits the form.
I designed it this way,

User Model

- Name: String
- Email: String
- Address: String
- Subscriptions: Array

Subscription Model

- Name: String

There is no relation between these two models except Subscription provides the available subscriptions in user form.
Once user pick and submit the form, subscription ids are stored as array inside the User model.
This is all working fine upto submitting, but when user clicks edit to change subscriptions I dont know or I fail to render the collection_check_boxes with his original subscriptions checked off.
Is there a design flaw in how the models are created? I cant wrap my head around using relations like embeds_many, embedded_in for my scenario above.

For below code, when user tried to edit, I get this error in edit form

```
undefined method `id' for "5733af2e54c870ee8190950b":String
```

```html
  <div class="checkbox">
    <% if @user.new_record? %>
      <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:subscriptions, Subscription.all, :id, :name) do |b| %>
        <%= b.label class:"label-checkbox" do %>
          <%= b.check_box + b.text %>
            |
        <%end%>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:subscriptions, Subscription.all, :id, :name,  { checked: @user.subscriptions.map(&:id) }) do |b| %>
        <%= b.label class:"label-checkbox" do %>
          <%= b.check_box + b.text %>
            |
        <%end%>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out myself, so collection checkbox helper method is calling `id` method on the subscriptions returned. But I store the subscription ids as array of string in User model, it is unable to call `id` method on string values. So I wrote a helper method in controller to return the actual subscriptions object from Subscription model. Now all working

```
  def get_subscriptions(user)
    Subscription.find(user.subscriptions)
  end
  helper_method :get_subscriptions
```

```html
    <% if @user.new_record? %>
      <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:subscriptions, Subscription.all, :id, :name) do |b| %>
        <%= b.label class:"label-checkbox" do %>
          <%= b.check_box + b.text %>
            |
        <%end%>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:subscriptions, Subscription.all, :id, :name,  { checked: get_subscriptions(@user).map(&:id) }) do |b| %>
        <%= b.label class:"label-checkbox" do %>
          <%= b.check_box + b.text %>
            |
        <%end%>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```